# How can I fill SQL Server table from excel only using sql query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

How can I do that with  Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_Temp] ( 
    [FirstName]   VARCHAR(20), 
    [LastName]    VARCHAR(20), 
    [Address]     VARCHAR(50), 
    [City]        VARCHAR(30), 
    [State]       VARCHAR(2), 
    [ZIP]         VARCHAR(10) 
) 
GO 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Address_Temp] ( [FirstName], [LastName], [Address], [City], [State], [ZIP] ) 
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Address], [City], [State], [ZIP] 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Source\Addresses.xlsx;IMEX=1', 
                'SELECT * FROM [Sayfa1$]')
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from sqlserver directly?

Answer (score 1):

That technique can work if the server can see the file (and the path is relative to the server).  Also, if it's on a share (or locally), then the account the server is acting under when it attempts to open the file needs to have sufficient rights to the share/directory/file.

The server also needs to have whatever provider you specify.

Are you seeing a particular error?